# echoing dynamically generated variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
set CSS_FOLDER_SOURCE=.\css
set JS_FOLDER_SOURCE=.\js



for %%A in (JS, CSS ) do (

    if defined %%A_FOLDER_SOURCE (
        echo  %%%A_FOLDER_SOURCE%%
    )
)
```

I want to read the contents of both folders. But don't know how to dynamically generate the FOLDER_SOURCE names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I call a dynamic variable name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621708/how-would-i-call-a-dynamic-variable-name)

Comment: If this duplicate is okay I'll delete my answer as unnecessary.

Comment: You may review the details of this management at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

............
for %%A in (JS CSS) do (
    echo !%%A_FOLDER_SOURCE!
)
```

Comment: And how may I assign this  !%%A_FOLDER_SOURCE! to another variable?

Comment: `set anotherVariable=!%%A_FOLDER_SOURCE!`, then you can use it `echo !anotherVariable!`